# Create video thumbnails from path

Tags: android-image

I'm trying for some time to create thumbnails from video without success. In fact I found several solutions on web but none work on all Android versions.

The only method that seems to work, works by using the id of the video. My problem is I need to use the video path but i don't find a way to do that. (no method works on all versions of Android.)

I need a solution that works on all versions greater than 2.0 would be sufficient.

Could you help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) could help?

Comment: Consider improving your post since your answer is essentially a link. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/156620) and [Why is linking bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/156620)

Comment: @Bavarious. Generally, I agree with you. But in this case the link points directly to the solution, so I considered additional comments not useful. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i resolved it:

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mSeconFilePath,
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mVideoView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumbnail));
    } else {
        mVideoView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumbnail));
    }
```